# Plugin to duplicate / clone any custom post type definition

Tags: cms, wordpress, plug-in

Looking for WordPress plugin recommendation. Plugin must clone or duplicate the ***custom post type (CPT) definition***. I already have Yoast Duplicate Post, but it only duplicates ***instances*** of a CPT.

Use Case:

- Create a custom post type with CPT UI and ACF Pro called "Video"
- Use a plugin to duplicate the post type definition to a new CPT, "Live Video"
- Live Video CPT can then be edited as needed
- The plugin should copy and associate the same ACF fields, etc.

I know how to do this manually by creating a new CPT, but then I have to go through and check enable/disable settings again. Is there a plugin that will duplicate the CPT settings for me? I know that I can duplicate ACF fieldsets, but I'm looking to eliminate as much work as possible.

I am using a child theme, of course.

I also found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372920/how-to-duplicate-entire-custom-post-type), but I'm looking for a code-free solution.